# Permissions trouble to run a Google Sites widget

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sites

I've just created a simple chatbot in HTML JS and CSS connected with Google Apps Script. As Google Suite administrator, I need to allow users run the script embedded in a Google site page. The problem is that the users need EDIT permission instead READ permission in the page. Anyone knows why? Other solutions I made run with READ permission only. When I deploy it, I set  run as me, and anyone in the domain can access to script, but if the permission is READ in the site page, the script doesn't run properly.

Comment: How do you connected your chatbot with Google Apps Script? How do you embedded the script on the page? Is this script a Google Apps Script published web app?

Comment: Yes. The script is published as a web app and embedded in a Google site but the permissions in the page for the users must be EDIT to run it.That's the issue. Thanks

Comment: What about the way that you connected your chatbot? By the way, are you using the old or the new Google Sites?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the old google sites and I just started to learh javascript so it musn't be difficult. It is ok if I write in spanish? I apologize for that, but your name is spanish so...

Comment: Primero me descargué una plantilla de un chat en HTML JS y CSS (hay muchas) y después de la respuesta corro un google.script.run para evaluar la respuesta en GAS. y obtengo un objeto JS en el return. Luego trato ese objeto para representarlo en el HTML.

Comment: If you prefer to post in Spanish, then use [es.so]. I'm an active member there too. Si prefieres publicar en español entonces usa [es.so]. Allá también participo de forma activa.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem with a very simple web app.

The following app shows a button. When the user click it, shows an alert.

**.gs file**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

**.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onClick="alert('Hola mundo')" value="Has click aquí">
  </body>
</html>
```

On the an old Google Site,

1. Create the web app
2. Create a page
3. Click on Insert > Google Apps Script
4. Select the web app

When opening the web page it shows a warning telling that the user doesn't have access to the resource.

To fix this, instead of selecting the web on step 4, paste the web URL on the field to do so.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work for me. Instead, I added each user separately with read permission and then the script works. It seems that the group's permission doesn't work fine with this script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarioMorenoGonzález That is a important detail. Please consider to post your solution as answer.